# Using multiple color maps with masked arrays in Matplotlib with contourf

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to visualize a classification model's output on a 2D plane during progressive stages of training. I'm generating simulated data that has four classes, and the model produces softmax output - for each data point in the grid, the model yields a length-four vector, say: [0.1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2], representative of the probability that the model gives that data point of being in each of the classes. In this case, we would say that the model predicted class 1 for the data point, because that's the highest probability among the four.

What I'm trying to do is visualize the decision boundary of the classifier using both the prediction of the model and the probability given by the model.  I'd like, for each data point on the grid, for the color to represent the class that the model predicted and the darkness of the color to represent the probability, with 0.25 being white and 1.0 being the darkest color in that gradient. (0.25 being white because [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25] is the most confused the model can be).  I'm using the following code to generate my plot, which compares two very similar models:

```
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(4, 7), dpi=80, sharex=True,       sharey=True)
f.suptitle("Training Set and Decision Boundary, Batch={0}".format(batch))
f.tight_layout(rect=[0, 0.03, 1, 0.95])

cmaps = ["Purples","Greens","Oranges","Blues"]

ax1.set_title("Baseline Model")
ax1.set_xlim([-10,10])
ax1.set_ylim([-10,10])
ax2.set_title("Modified Model")
ax2.set_xlim([-10,10])
ax2.set_ylim([-10,10])

u = np.unique(p1)

# Loop through the predicted classes, using a masked array to set the points predicted to be that class

for i in range(len(u)):
    c = u[i]

    xx_tmp = np.ma.masked_array(xx, p1 == c)
    yy_tmp = np.ma.masked_array(yy, p1 == c)
    z_tmp = np.ma.masked_array(z1, p1 == c)

    ax1.contourf(xx_tmp, yy_tmp, z_tmp, cmap=cmaps[c])

u = np.unique(p2)

for i in range(len(u)):
    c = u[i]

    xx_tmp = np.ma.masked_array(xx, p2 == c)
    yy_tmp = np.ma.masked_array(yy, p2 == c)
    z_tmp = np.ma.masked_array(z2, p2 == c)

    ax2.contourf(xx_tmp, yy_tmp, z_tmp, cmap=cmaps[c])


plt.savefig(VIS_DIR + "Batch{0}.png".format(batch))
plt.gcf().clear()
```

I'm using 10,000 points in a 100 x 100 grid to give the contourf function. z1 and z2 are 100 x 100 numpy arrays that store the highest probability among the prediction vector for each data point. p1 and p2 are 100 x 100 arrays that store the predicted class (0, 1, 2, 3) for each data point.

This code kind of works, but for some reason I only get a maximum of two colors and I don't understand why (I've verified that my prediction arrays have the correct labels in them).  Here are two examples:

[image: Plot output after batch 200]

[image: Plot output after batch 400]

It's pretty easy to see where the decision boundaries are, and it's easy to see the four classes and the increasing model confidence with more training. But why are three of the classes blue? I only ever get a maximum of two colors. If I reorder the colors in the cmaps list then the colors I get change, so I think it has something to do with matplotlib overwriting previous passes. Is there anything here that is incorrect?  Should I even be using masked arrays and contourf or is there an easier way to do this?

Thank you!!

Comment: Your code does not run, see [mcve]. So one has to guess here. Possibly, you are masking the wrong regions here. Instead of masking the region where the current loop index is equal to the class you might want to mask where it is unequal, `np.ma.masked_array(xx, p1 != c)`.

Comment: You're right on all counts. I omitted the part of the code that constructs the data because I didn't want the code block to be too long.  I'll write a simple case in the future.

And you solved it!  I was masking what I wanted, not what I didn't want.  I changed the script to use masked_where and inverted the conditional, now it works as intended.  Thanks!

Comment: Two options: If you think this question can be useful for future readers, please provide an answer to it yourself, which you can accpet in 2 days time. If not, you may as well delete it.